# Saving QGLPixelBuffer to file gives blank image

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a Qt console program which is supposed to render a scene from a number of viewpoints and save each rendering to a file. It runs is as follows:

```
for(int k = 0; k < numberOfViewpoints; ++k)
{
    RenderToQGLPixelBuffer(k);
    QString fname = GetFileName(k);
    QImage im = pixBuffer->toImage();
    im.save(fname);
}
```

If I do it like this, all of the images end up blank. However if I make the program sleep for one second after saving the image:

```
for(int k = 0; k < numberOfViewpoints; ++k)
{
    RenderToQGLPixelBuffer(k);
    QString fname = GetFileName(k);
    QImage im = pixBuffer->toImage();
    im.save(fname);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

then it works as expected and the images come out fine. However, this obviously increases the processing time considerably. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might try qApp->processEvents() after you call RenderToGLPixelBuffer(k).

Another possible issue is that the pixel buffer is still drawing when you go to read it back. Try calling glFinish() when you are done drawing.